# Can I expense the rent for a three month contract abroad

Tags: united-kingdom, limited-liability-company, working-abroad

I am a consultant living in UK using my own limited company.

If I accept a contract to work in another European country, can I expense the rent I will have there?

Comment: Yes you can, but it is a bit tricky. I would advise to contact your accountant.

Comment: @DJClayworth the first its his limited company